# Generalization of the The Liouville Lambda function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, arithmetic-functions

Let $n=p^{\alpha_1}_1 \cdots p^{\alpha_m}_m,$ and define
$$\lambda_k(n)= (-1)^{ [\frac{\Omega(n)}{k} ]},$$
where $\Omega(n)= \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_k,$ and $[\cdot]$  is the  floor function.

For $k=1$, $\lambda_1$ is the Liouvilles Lambda  function. For $k=2$:

$\lambda_2(1)=1, \hspace{2 mm} \lambda_2(p_1)=1, \hspace{2 mm} \lambda_2(p_1p_2)=-1, \hspace{2 mm} \lambda_2(p_1p_2p_3)=-1 \hspace{2 mm} \text{ and so on...}.$

-Is there anythig known about this function?

-If for $\Re(s)>1$ we define $$L(s, \lambda_2):= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda_2(n)}{n^s},$$

Is there any connection between $L_{\lambda_2}(s)$ and the zeros of the Riemann zeta function?

-I guess (without knowing how to prove) that $$\sum_{n<x} \lambda_2(n) = o(x),$$
smilar to $\lambda_1$ should we expect square root cancelation on sum of $\lambda_2$ as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's just consider the case $k=2$; you can try to generalize this argument for larger $k$.  For $k=2$,
$$ 
\sum_{n\le x} \lambda_2(n) = \sum_{\substack{ n\le x \\ \Omega(n) = 0,1 \mod 4}} 1 - \sum_{\substack{ n\le x \\ \Omega(n) = 2,3 \mod 4}} 1. 
$$
This can be expressed as
$$ 
\text{Re} \sum_{n\le x} i^{\Omega(n)} + \text{Im} \sum_{n\le x}i^{\Omega(n)},
$$
and now one can use Selberg--Delange.  This will show an asymptotic expansion for $\sum_{n\le x} i^{\Omega(n)}$, and the leading term in the asymptotic is
$$ 
C x (\log x)^{i-1}, 
$$
for a suitable constant $C$.  Thus you can find an asymptotic for your sum, which will be of the form
$$ 
A \cos(\log \log x) \frac{x}{\log x} + B \sin(\log \log x) \frac{x}{\log x},
$$
for suitable constants $A$ and $B$.  Weird!  But then you're also looking at a weird object!

Comment: Indeed, it's closely related to what Tian An Wong, Snehal Shekatkar, and I studied in this paper (again using Selberg-Delange): https://doi.org/10.5802/jtnb.1066